# xcode showing error - 'appendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I know this has been asked before but how to go about this in my case -

```
 import Stripe

 class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
 let baseURL = "https://api.stripe.com"
 func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
 let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")  /*1st error - 'appendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead.*/
 var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)! /*2nd error - Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL'*/
 urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
 var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
 guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
 response.statusCode == 200,
 let data = data,
 let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(json, nil)
    })
    task.resume()
   }
 }
```

i) I am using

a)swift

b)firestore

c) nodejs - should I use something else instead of node js ?

Also, what other modifications should I do?  All other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `baseURL` is a String. `appendingPathComponent(_:)` is a `(NS)URL` method, not a String one. `init(url:resolvingAgainstBaseURL:)` expects a `URL` for its first parameter, not a `String`. Stop mixing type, read them carefully. They might look alike, but it's like an Orange and a clementine. Different.

Comment: @Larme Confusingly the API still exists in `NSString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has removed the path modification APIs from `String` for a long time.

You have to create an URL, that's what the error is suggesting

```
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com")!
```

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks, the error is now gone. Also, I am using node.js. Is it the best thing to do ? Any further suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with node.js, sorry.